# Reboot virtual machine automatically when the physical computer restarts (VMWare)

Tags: windows, virtualization, vmware-server

How to do it with the free version of VMWare or any other windows free virtualization software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My method:

1. Set up a remote interactive session to autostart (follow the instructions at http://wiki.imacros.net/How_to_Schedule_a_RemoteInteractive_Session - its easier then it sounds!)
2. Create a shortcut to the vmware machine(s) you need to autostart and drag them to the autostart folder.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some instructions how to do it on VMware Server:

http://www.petri.co.il/automatically-power-up-vmware-server-guest-os.htm

It's easier to look for starting a VM on power up since it is the same as rebooting on a restart.